# numpy 2d array (coordinates) need to assign into 3D array, to some particular bin

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, indexing

I have the following code to compute HOG image with 8 bins and pre-counted Sobel X and Y filtered image:

```
for y in xrange(0, 480):
    for x in xrange(0, 640):
        base_angle = np.arctan2(sobel_Y[y,x], sobel_X[y,x]) * 180/np.pi
        if base_angle < 0: base_angle += 360
        angle = int(round(base_angle / 45))
        if angle == 8: angle = 0
        hog[y,x,angle] += np.sqrt(sobel_X[y,x]**2 + sobel_Y[y,x]**2)
```

I was trying to modify it to avoid loops:

```
base_angle = np.arctan2(sobel_Y, sobel_X) * 180/np.pi
base_angle[base_angle < 0] += 360
angle =(base_angle / 45).round().astype(np.uint8)
angle[angle == bins] = 0
hog[:,:,angle] += np.sqrt(sobel_X**2 + sobel_Y**2)
```

However, the last expression does not count correctly. What I basically need is to have the magnitude (np.sqrt... expression) being added to hog array according to index from angle array, at every (y,x) point of hog array. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
magnitude = np.sqrt(sobel_X**2 + sobel_Y**2)
Y, X = np.ogrid[0:angle.shape[0], 0:angle.shape[1]]
hog[Y, X, angle] += magnitude
```

to update `hog`.

---

```
import numpy as np

def using_for_loop(hog, sobel_Y, sobel_X):
    for y in xrange(0, sobel_Y.shape[0]):
        for x in xrange(0, sobel_X.shape[1]):
            base_angle = np.arctan2(sobel_Y[y, x], sobel_X[y, x]) * 180 / np.pi
            if base_angle < 0:
                base_angle += 360
            angle = int(round(base_angle / 45))
            if angle == 8:
                angle = 0
            hog[y, x, angle] += np.sqrt(sobel_X[y, x] ** 2 +
                                        sobel_Y[y, x] ** 2)
    return hog

def using_indexing(hog, sobel_Y, sobel_X):
    base_angle = np.arctan2(sobel_Y, sobel_X) * 180 / np.pi
    base_angle[base_angle < 0] += 360
    angle = (base_angle / 45).round().astype(np.uint8)
    angle[angle == bins] = 0
    magnitude = np.sqrt(sobel_X ** 2 + sobel_Y ** 2)
    Y, X = np.ogrid[0:angle.shape[0], 0:angle.shape[1]]
    hog[Y, X, angle] += magnitude
    return hog

bins = 8
sobel_Y, sobel_X = np.meshgrid([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7])
# hog = np.zeros(sobel_X.shape + (bins,))
hog = np.random.random(sobel_X.shape + (bins,))
answer = using_for_loop(hog, sobel_Y, sobel_X)
result = using_indexing(hog, sobel_Y, sobel_X)
assert np.allclose(answer, result)
```

---

Note that if

```
In [62]: angle.shape
Out[62]: (4, 3)
```

then

```
In [74]: hog[:,:,angle].shape
Out[74]: (4, 3, 4, 3)
```

That's not the right shape. Rather, if you define

```
In [75]: Y, X = np.ogrid[0:angle.shape[0], 0:angle.shape[1]]
```

then `hog[Y, X, angle]` has the same shape as `magnitude`:

```
In [76]: hog[Y, X, angle].shape
Out[76]: (4, 3)

In [77]: magnitude = np.sqrt(sobel_X ** 2 + sobel_Y ** 2)

In [78]: magnitude.shape
Out[78]: (4, 3)
```

Of course, that is not a proof that `hog[Y, X, angle]` is the correct expression, but it is the equivalent of a physicist's [dimensionality check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) which shows we at least could be on the right track.

---

With [NumPy fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing), when `Y`, `X`, and `angle` all have the same shape (or broadcast to the same shape),

```
hog[Y, X, angle]
```

will also be of the same shape. The `(i,j)`th element in `hog[Y, X, angle]` will equal

```
hog[Y[i,j], X[i,j], angle[i,j]]
```

This is why `hog[Y, X, angle] += magnitude` works.

Comment: 10ms! awesome, thank you! :)
was thiking something like indexed arrays should be in every dimension, but was not sure if there is a solution, now i got it, thanx!